# how to use setInterval globally in react and recoil?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, setinterval, recoiljs

how to use setInterval in react?

I want to make a timer that runs global.
But I don't know where to use setInterval.
Timer stops when the page moves..
I hope the timer will continue even if the page doesn't change using recoil.

Even if it's not a recoil, please help me to execute the setInterval globally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.